# How to re-enable Code Download from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there anyway to re-enable the Code Download option from Google App Engine.  I stupidly and totally mouse-fluke clicked it and have no idea on how to re-enable that option back so that I can download it.

I was just in there looking at it.  It didnt even asks me for a confirmation!!
help

Comment: It does ask for confirmation and clearly says its permanent.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a one way setting. There's no way to' revert it.